# Is strong convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $F_n(f) = f(\frac{1}{n}) - f(-\frac{1}{n}) \in \big ( C^{(1)} [-1, 1] \big ) ^*$.

For every $f \in C^{(1)} [-1, 1]$ we have pointwise limit:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n (f) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \big ( f(\frac{1}{n}) - f(-\frac{1}{n}) \big ) = f(0+) - f(0-) = 0,
$$

because $f$ is continious. Is $F_n$ convergence strong to $0$?

I tryed to calculate limit

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \lVert F_n - 0 \rVert = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lVert F_n \rVert = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{\lVert f \rVert \le 1} |f(\frac{1}{n}) - f(-\frac{1}{n}),|
$$
but how calculate that supremum?

Comment: It think that the supremum doesn't go to zero. You can always find a function $f_n \in C^{\infty}$ that take value $1$ on $[\frac{1}{2n},\frac{3}{2n}]$ and 0 on $[-1,0]$ and that is always lower or equals than $1$. Such that $|F_n(f_n)|=1$. I don't recall the name in English though...It's used to approximate the characteristic function of a compact with a test function.

Comment: $C^{\infty}$ or $C^{(1)}$?

Comment: I may have been confused, what norm do you use on $C^{(1)}$ when you write $||f|| \leq 1$ ? The functions I propose are $C^{\infty}$ hence $C^{1}$ but when I say they are in the unit ball, I'm speaking about $||.||_{\infty}$ norm

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\|F_n\|\to 0$. The reason is that for every $f$ in the unit ball of $C^1$ we have
$$|f(1/n)-f(-1/n)|\le \frac{2}{n} \sup|f'| \le \frac2n  $$

---

(However, this would not hold if  $C^1$ was replaced with $C^0$.)